# Unable to get Material UI dropdown options to appear

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a custom dropdown component:

```
<FormControl fullWidth required>
            <InputLabel id="dataset-select-label">Dataset</InputLabel>
            <Select
                id='dataset-select'
                labelId="dataset-select-label"
                variant="outlined"
                label={'Dataset'}
                disabled={loadingDetails}
                value={selectedDatasetId !== undefined ? selectedDatasetId + '' : ''}
                onChange={handleDatasetChange}
            >
                { dataSets.map( (option, index ) => (
                    <MenuItem key={'upload-' + index} value={ option.id }>
                        <span>{option.name}</span>
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

And I'm testing it like this:

```
it('should dispatch a dataset selection change', async () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
        mockGetAvailableDatasets.mockResolvedValue(mockDatasets);

        const { getByRole } = render(
            <MethodologyContext.Provider value={{pageStore: initialState, dispatch: mockDispatch}}>
                <DataSetSelector />
            </MethodologyContext.Provider>
        );

        await waitFor(() => expect(mockGetAvailableDatasets).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));

        const dropdown = screen.getByRole('button', {name: /Dataset/});
        await selectDataset(dropdown, mockDatasets[1].name);

        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'dataset', value: mockDatasets[1].id });
    });
```

where selectDataset looks like:

```
async function selectDataset(dropDown: HTMLElement, datasetName: string, timeout: number = 10000) {
    fireEvent.click(dropDown);

    await waitFor(async () => {
        const listbox = await screen.findByRole('listbox', {}, {timeout: timeout});

        const option = await within(listbox).findByRole('option', {name: datasetName}, {timeout: timeout});

        fireEvent.click(option);
    }, { timeout: 20000 });
}
```

The `fireEvent.click(dropDown);` isn't triggering the dropdown. I've tried increasing timeouts, using `mouseDown`, and other things, but I still get:

`Unable to find role="listbox"`

Any ideas of what might be going on?

Comment: Prefer [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) over the built-in `fireEvent`. Also check that the dropdown indeed has a `listbox` role, it can be `combobox` instead. More pointers [here](https://claritydev.net/blog/testing-select-components-react-testing-library).